# Why is the Photo Id not being passed to create action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm implementing likes for photos, and the id isn't being passed. I don't know why. Could someone please explain why? I feel it would help me understand rails better.

I get this error, after clicking like: "Couldn't find Photo without an ID"

On the photo show page I have this:

```
<%= form_for(@photolike, :url => {:controller => :photolikes, :action => 'create'}) do |f| %>
<%= f.hidden_field :photo_id, :value => @photo.id %> 
<%= f.submit "like", class: "btn postbtn right" %>
<% end %>
```

this is the controller for photos

```
def show
if user_signed_in?
 @comment = current_user.sent_photocoments.new(params[:photo_comment])
 end
 @photo = Photo.find(params[:id])
 @photolike = Photolike.new
end
```

And in the photolikes controller, I have this:

```
def create
 @photo = Photo.find(params[:id])
 @photolike = Photolike.new(:photo_id => @photo.id, :user_id => current_user.id)
 @photolike.addlike
 @photolike.save
 redirect_to @photo
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def create
 @photo = Photo.find(params[:photolike][:photo_id])
 @photolike = Photolike.new(:photo_id => @photo.id, :user_id => current_user.id)
 @photolike.addlike
 @photolike.save
 redirect_to @photo
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Your submit is submitting the photo_id labeled as `photo_id` (in your hidden field). So your controller needs to retrieve it via `params[:photo_id]` rather than `params[:id]`.

Comment: Thanks for your help mbratch. yeah, but I've tried that before, too. It still doesn't work. I get the same error.

Comment: You didn't specify which module was complaining. You still need to use `params[:photo_id]` since that's what you're passing to the controller. The error message might then be pertaining to the `show` action, but I cannot tell because there are pieces missing in your question (e.g, what the show view looks like, etc).

Comment: thanks mbratch. If I use @photo = Photo.find(params[:photo_id])in the create action, i still get this error: Couldn't find Photo without an ID. The ID is being grabbed in the form, so I'm pretty confused.

Comment: Look at `development.log` and see the parameters coming into the request - it should be obvious what the appropriate `params` key/value pair you need

Comment: @CodyCaughlan the param is being passed  "photolike"=>{"photo_id"=>"15"}

Comment: @CodyCaughlan could it because I have two forms in the photo show page getting the photo id? I have one for comments and one for likes...